# Prime number function returns true instead of false

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python with Codecademy. I am on exercise 6 called "is_prime". I wrote the function step by step from the instructions, but it returns True instead of False. Why?

Instructions:

[image: Instructions]

My code:

```
def is_prime(x):             # step 1
    for n in range(2,x-1):   # step 2
        if (x % n) == 0:     # step 3
            return False
    else:                    # step 4
        return True
```

Error: Your function fails on is_prime(0). It returns True when it should return False.

Comment: How often do you think a `for n in range(2, 0-1)` loop is going to run? How is the function supposed to return `False` if it never even enters the loop?

Comment: You have not covered the edge cases.

Comment: Found the solution. How do I close this thread ?

Comment: @lextragon Topics can be closed as off-topic by users with the voting rights to do so. You can accept an answer to indicate that the question is solved, though. edit: The option to accept an answer will be available 15 minutes after asking the question.

Comment: You mark the answer that helped you best with a checkmark next to the answer score.

Comment: Your solution is very inefficient, by the way. No need to check for factors above `sqrt(x)`, and you should not be checking factors again and again - look up Sieve of Erasthosthenes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 0 you should have extra if condition

```
def is_prime(x):             # step 1
    if(x==0 or x==1):
        return False
    for n in range(2,x-1):   # step 2
        if (x % n) == 0:     # step 3
            return False
    else:                    # step 4
        return True
```

Comment: Can I add that statement next to the one that's in the for loop ?

Comment: @mastro35 i have edited the code now. kindly check it for is_prime(1) now

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop never runs, because `range(2, 0-1)` is empty. This means that the `else` block executes (think of `for/else` as `for/nobreak`) which returns `True`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: the else statement is completely useless, you can simply remove it.
Beside, what's contained in the for loop doesn't run when you pass 0, 1 or 2 as a parameter because the loop starts from 2 and ends at the parameter's value - 1.

To get your function working you can change it as follows:

```
def is_prime(x):
    for n in range(2,x-1):
            if (x%n) == 0:
                    return False
    return (True if x>1 else False)
```

Dave

Comment: You don't have to use ternary , you could just use boolean, eg `return x > 0` .  Still , it works fine .

Comment: That's true, but it seems more easy to read for me in this way than writing simply return x>1 ... good catch tough :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want...

0 and 1 are never prime, so should always return False.

The number 2 should return True, but won't fit conveniently in the range() function, as described by other commenters.

```
def is_prime(x):             # step 1
    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(2,x-1):   # step 2
        if x % n == 0:       # step 3
            return False
    else:                    # step 4
        return True
```

Comment: What if I wrote `if x < 2:` and `return False` ? Would the number 2 return `True` ?